# How to set file destination for to a certain map?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code and I would like to save the file in a certain map on my pc.

How could I add a custom path, so I could change it in the future when needed?

As of now it just saves on my desktop.

Code:

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd") & " Testing"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
Testing = "C:\Testing\" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd") & " Testing " & ".xlsx"
MsgBox "File saved in: C:\Testing\" & vbNewLine & "Your_Second_Text"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Testing, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way:-

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd") & " Testing.xlsx"

You can replace "C:\Users" with any path. But please don't forget to add the file extension at the end.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply for some reason I'm getting an error with the number 400 in it.

Comment: This is funny: In my above code there is a back slash following "Users" - between the path and the file name. This is necessary and it's actually in my post (I can see it in edit mode) but the site doesn't display it. Please add it in your code.

Comment: Should be:
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd") & " Testing.xlsx" ?
Still geting this 400 error :(

Comment: The definition I get for error 400 is "Corrupt download or deficient installation of Microsoft Excel software." They recommend to run "Repair Excel". Try the code with a simple path which you are sure does exist.

Comment: Mmm weird I tried a simple path, just made still getting error 400 :O